# Linux & Virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is it possible to create different *Linux OS* in Virtual Box and set different `IP` address and ping one host through the other?

I configured `2` Linux running on Virtual box with different `IP` address but when I ping the other one i get no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, what i can recommend you is to connect the virtual machines in bridge mode so each machine has a ip and is shared with your host machine

Comment: Thank you so much.. in that case, can i work with different scenario? i mean assigning half duplex to one and full duplex to the other with different speeds !? and do they work with different MAC addresses? since the NIC has a specific MAC address!

Comment: yes, you can work with different mac addresses, but not sure if will work as should work in a real environment with the half and full duplex

Answer (score 0):

Yes is very possible.
There is several ways to achive this. One is use "Bridged Networkin".
You can see more here[Virtual Box - Network configuration](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Comment: Thank you so much.. in that case, can i work with different scenario? i mean assigning half duplex to one and full duplex to the other with different speeds !? and do they work with different MAC addresses? since the NIC has a specific MAC address!

Answer (score 0):

It should work as @Arthur85 said, set the vms into bridge mode. If it does not work, then check whether they are in the same subnet. If it does not work even in the same subnet, check the iptable rules.

Comment: Thank you so much.. in that case, can i work with different scenario? i mean assigning half duplex to one and full duplex to the other with different speeds !? and do they work with different MAC addresses? since the NIC has a specific MAC address!